# Continual input in a while loop keeps repeating?

Tags: bash, shell

I've created a bash script that acts as a simple calculator. The goal of the calculator is to keep asking the user for input. This input includes the operation and the two numbers.

However, I am running into a problem where after submitting the first operation, the `while` loop will keep executing on that initial operation.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Calculator"
echo "Input an Operation: +, -, *, /, and % (0 to stop): "
read OP

while [ $OP != "0" ]
do
    if [ $OP == "+" ]; then
        echo "Add Numbers"
        SUM=0
        echo "Enter number1: "
        read N1

        echo "Enter number2: "
        read N2

        SUM=$((N1+N2))

        echo "Result: $SUM"
    elif [ $OP == "-" ]; then
        echo "Subtract Numbers"
        SUB=0
        echo "Enter number1: "
        read N1

        echo "Enter number2: "
        read N2

        SUB=$((N1-N2))

        echo "Result: $SUB"
    elif [ $OP == "*" ]; then
        echo "Multiple Numbers"
        MUL=0
        echo "Enter number1: "
        read N1

        echo "Enter number2: "
        read N2

        MUL=$((N1*N2))

        echo "Result: $MUL"
    elif [ $OP == "/" ]; then
        echo "Divide Numbers"
        DIV=0
        echo "Enter number1: "
        read N1

        echo "Enter number2: "
        read N2

        DIV=$((N1/N2))

        echo "Result: $DIV"
    elif [ $OP == "%" ]; then
        echo "Modulus Numbers"
        SUB=0
        echo "Enter number1: "
        read N1

        echo "Enter number2: "
        read N2

        MOD=$((N1%N2))

        echo "Result: $MOD"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

I know this is something small but haven't been able to figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: You are saying *enter '0' to stop* but never go back to prompt for the operator. Your loop just loops on entering numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the initial prompt *inside* the loop.

Instead of:

```
echo "Input an Operation: +, -, *, /, and % (0 to stop): "
read OP

while [ $OP != "0" ]
do
    ...
```

Do this:

```
while [ $OP != "0" ]
do
    echo "Input an Operation: +, -, *, /, and % (0 to stop): "
    read OP
    ...
```